# Unable to get twilio gather to work

Tags: php, twilio

I'm using twilio to call a user and am having trouble collecting the users input. The initial call works fine, but when I press 1 or 3, nothing appears to happen, and after the 3 second pause, it keeps going.

```
//This works fine, I can call and hear the options being read.
<?php
  header("content-type: text/xml");
  echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
  <Gather action="https://mydomain.com/twilio/process_response.php" method="post" numDigits="1" timeout="3">
    <Say>I can hear this.</Say>
    <Say>Press 1.</Say>
    <Say>Press 3.</Say>
   </Gather>
<Say>It looks like you didn't select an option.</Say>
</Response>
```

The response - https://mydomain.com/twilio/process_response.php

```
<?php 
 header("content-type: text/xml");
 echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
<Say>I should hear this, but I dont...</Say>
</Response>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to test with? Some services like google voice or skype don't send touch tones very well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I was using a cordless phone from a (comcast) land line. I just tried dialing a cellphone instead and it worked perfectly. It must be something with the cordless phone. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was caused by the cordless phone I was using to test not recognising the input. Changing phones "solved" this issue.

Answer (score 3):

`<Gather>` works by listening to the [DTMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling) sounds that your phone or device produces. Things that would make it difficult for you to hear what a person on the other end is saying can also make it difficult for Twilio to recognize DTMF tones. Poor mobile phone reception, excessive background noise, or connection that has lots of static can all make it difficult for `<Gather>` to recognize digit presses.

In addition, VoIP phones can be installed with a non-standard DTMF tones as the default, which Twilio will also have difficulty recognizing. VoIP phones might also be using pretty strong compression which can interfere with DTMF. In either case, consulting the phone's manual or the person who installed the phone is usually a good next step.

Browser or application based VoIP, like Skype or Google Voice, sometimes also have trouble with `<Gather>` for the same reasons VoIP phones have trouble.

Twilio's `<Gather>` troubleshooting link: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

> The 'action' attribute takes an absolute or relative URL as a value.

From looking in their documentation, it appears that the action attribute can only contain "/page.php" or "page.php". You'll need to drop the protocol and host portion. So:

```
<Gather action="/twilio/process_response.php" method="post" numDigits="1" timeout="3">
```

Comment: You can use a full URL no problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried all possible URL's, so am not sure it's related to the action.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. 

Later, I found this issue disappeared after  appending **finishOnKey** ie  **#** 

 or any other **'custom finishOnKey'**

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue.
Appending finishOnKey didn't work either.

My solution was to use speech recognition  (input="speech"), i.e. not using DTMF, which is not reliable enough.